# problems with tikzmarkin

Tags: tikz-pgf, hf-tikz

I write a math script which is sectioned in different themes and have the following problem:
In one section I use `tikzmarkin` and it works in the section (its own document) but when I copy it in the whole script I get the following problem:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

In my main file I have the same and more usepackages as in the one which works with `tikzmarkin`.

Here is a mini example which works in the small file but not in the main one.

```
\[
\left|
\begin{array}{*{3}{c}}
\tikzmarkin{c}(0.1,-0.1) 6^{+} & 0^{-} & 8^{+} \tikzmarkend{c}\\ -4^{-} & 10^{+} & 2^{-} \\ 3^{+} & 1^{-} & 4^{+}
\end{array}
\right|
\]
```

Comment: please provide complete but small document which will show your problem. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You need to compile two times as the first only creates references in the auxiliary files. The second allows to exploit such references to draw the background.

Answer (score 2):

It runs without problems on my TeXLive 2018 distribution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\begin{document}
\[
\left|
\begin{array}{*{3}{c}}
\tikzmarkin{c}(0.1,-0.1) 6^{+} & 0^{-} & 8^{+} \tikzmarkend{c}\\ -4^{-} & 10^{+} & 2^{-} \\ 3^{+} & 1^{-} & 4^{+}
\end{array}
\right|
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]